# Facing Issues in Java Higher Order Function. Not reaping the correct benefit of higher order function

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

**We need to get a list of all items which has a specific action. I know that I am not using the correct way of Higher Order Functions. Need insights how the third solution can be improved using higher-order functions and why this is taking too much of time.**

Solution 1: Using Depth-first search recursion without any java 8 functional programming

**Time Taken
0.07 msec**

```
 getitemsDFS(ItemRef po)
     {
           List<ItemRef> items = new ArrayList<>();
           for(Item child : po.getItem())
           {
                items.addAll(getAdditemsRec(child));
           }
           return items;
     }

 private List<ItemRef> getAdditemsRec(ItemRef child) {
       List<ItemRef> items = new ArrayList<>();
       if(SOME_ACTION.equals(child.getAction()))
       {
            items.add(child);
       }
       for(ItemRef childOI: child.getItem())
       {
            items.addAll(getAdditemsRec(childOI));
       }
       return items;
 }
```

Solution 2:  Using Breadth first search without any java 8 functional programming

**Time Taken
0.05 msec**

```
 private List<ItemRef> getAddOrderItemBFS(Item po) {
               
               List<ItemRef> items = new ArrayList<>();
               Deque<ItemRef> oIDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();
               oIDeque.addAll(po.getItem());
               while(!oIDequ

e.isEmpty())


   {
            ItemRef currentOI = oIDeque.removeFirst();
            if(ADD_ACTION.equals(currentOI.getAction()))
                  items.add(currentOI);
            if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(currentOI.getItem()))
                  oIDeque.addAll(currentOI.getItem());
       }
       return items;
 }
```

Solution3:  Using Functional Programming and Lambda Expression
**11.50 msec**

> This is approx. 200 times more than 1 & 2 we need to optimize this.
> Also it is not pure functional Programming as it involves ArrayList
> creation and assignment codes and imperative codes(how things to be
> done and not just what needs to be done). Not reaping the correct
> benefit of higher order function.

```
private List<ItemRef> getAdditemsFunctional(ItemRef po)
     {
           return po
                      .getItem()
                      .stream()
                      .map(oi->getitemsFunctionalRec(oi))
                      .flatMap(List::stream)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
     }

private List<ItemRef> getitemsFunctionalRec(ItemRef oi) {
           List<ItemRef> listOIs = new ArrayList<>();
           if(ADD_ACTION.equals(oi.getAction()))
           {
                listOIs.add(oi);
           }
           listOIs.addAll(oi.getItem()
                      .stream()
                      .map(childOI->getitemsFunctionalRec(childOI))
                      .flatMap(List::stream)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
           return listOIs;
     }
```

Comment: So you have a recursive data structure (like a tree) and want to flatten it and filter some data out of it? Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, @Amongalen. To be precise filter some data.

Comment: What's the difference between `ItemRef` and `Item`? Are those exactly the same class?

Comment: Yes, Same. They are same classes, Its a typo.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix typos.

Answer (score 2):

I probably won't answer your question directly on how to improve the 3rd solution but I'll suggest a different approach to the problem using `Stream`s. As you said in the comments you basicly want to flatten a recursive data structure (similar to a tree) and filter out some of the data. A possible way to do that is to make a method in `Item` that returns a flattened stream of all elements. The method inside of `Item` could look like this:

```
public Stream<Item> flattened() {
    return Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(this),
            items.stream().flatMap(Item::flattened));
}
```

Note that I use `items` variable in here. I assume that's the name of variable holding all children that is returned by `getItem` method.

Then you can use a result of that method as a regular `Stream` with all elements of the tree. You can simply filter data you want like this:

```
private static List<Item> getAdditemsFunctional(Item item) {
    return item.flattened()
        .filter(oi -> ADD_ACTION.equals(oi.getAction())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It's worth noting that I didn't test it myself and I'm not sure if it will be any faster than your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could optimize this by getting rid of unnecessary `collect` calls and keeping everything as a stream until the end:

```
private static List<ItemRef> getAdditemsFunctional(ItemRef po) {
    return getitemsFunctionalRec(po)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Stream<ItemRef> getitemsFunctionalRec(ItemRef oi) {

    Stream<ItemRef> result = oi
            .getItem()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(this::getitemsFunctionalRec);

    if (ADD_ACTION.equals(oi.getAction())) {
        result = Stream.concat(Stream.of(oi), result);
    }
    return result;
}
```